# Looking for a (preferably "all-zsh") alternative to printenv that can handle Unicode in variable names

Tags: zsh, unicode

`zsh` supports variable names with Unicode characters (if the `multibyte` option is set), but `printenv` (at least GNU's version 8.23 thereof) doesn't seem to be able to handle such variable names.

For example,

```
% export BANANAS=バナナス
% export バナナス=BANANAS
% /bin/echo -e "$BANANAS\n$バナナス"
バナナス
BANANAS
```

...but<sup>1</sup>

```
% printenv | grep BANANAS
BANANAS=バナナス
ャ\203\260ャ\203\252ャ\203\252ス=BANANAS
% printenv --version | head -1
printenv (GNU coreutils) 8.23
```

Is there an alternative to printenv that is capable of handling Unicode in variable names?  (For portability reasons, an "all-zsh" solution would be vastly preferable.)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Full disclosure: when I pasted the output of `printenv | grep BANANAS` from my screen into the StackExchange editor, some characters were automatically stripped off.  I've "simulated" these stripped off characters with strings specifying their octal codes (e.g. `\203\260`, etc.).  The result closely resembles the way the actual output looks on my screen.</sup>

Comment: By the way `printenv BANANAS` would just print `バナナス` and `printenv バナナス` would just print `BANANAS`. `printenv` can take an environment variable name as an argument and prints just the *value* of that one variable. This is the more "proper" way to use `printenv` the majority of the time and generally avoids issues like this in the first place. (Unfortunately it doesn't help in the rare case where we really do need or want to dump all environment variables in `name=value` form).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uh, sure, just use `export` (works in any Bourne-style shell), or `typeset -x`, or a few other variants. To print specific variables, you can use `typeset -p VAR1 VAR2 VAR3`.

These all print the values in a quoted form that can be re-read by zsh. If you want just `VARIABLE=VALUE` even if the value contains special characters, you can write a function:

```
zprintenv () {
  local __zprintenv_var
  if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then set -- $(typeset +mx); fi
  for __zprintenv_var do
    print $__zprintenv_var=${(P)__zprintenv_var}
  done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there isn't one because it would be non-POSIX.

Further reading:

- [getenv - Environment variable on Mac OS X and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478695/getenv-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x-and-linux)
- [Getting environment Variables as UTF-8 Strings in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652038/getting-environment-variables-as-utf-8-strings-in-linux)

Granted, `zsh` could implement an *extension*, but unless other applications can read the variables, they are of limited use.

Shell variables and environment variables are different, because shell variables can be stored in the shell interpreter's memory (and they are limited only by the shell interpreter itself), while environment variables are exported — made available for use by other programs.  That is why standards (such as POSIX) come into play.

Comment: Thanks for the links.  From them I figured that the problem goes all the way down to the way that Linux stores environment variables in `/proc/<pid>/environ`.  I imagine that `printenv` just returns the contents of `/proc/<pid>/environ`; same for `env`.  OTOH, `zsh` must have the *correct* names of its variables *somewhere*, as demonstrated by the `echo` command in my example...